# Firebase v9 signup a new user and store users in a users collection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am able to sign up a new user, but how can I store that user in a collection in firestore? I am not sure with firebase v9 if the addDoc function is in the right place, but I don't know where else or how to code it.

```
export const useSignup = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext();

  const signup = (email: string, password: string, username: string) => {
    setError("");
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: res.user });
        const uid = res.user.uid;
        const data = {
          id: uid,
          email,
          username,
        };
        const ref = collection(db, "users");
        addDoc(ref, {
          data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
      });
  };

  return { error, signup };
};
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a really inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend running the code in a debugger yourself, and then telling us the results. If you set a breakpoint on `addDoc(ref, {...})` and run in the debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? If so, do all variables have the value you expect? If so, and you step through code, do you get any error message?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I fixed it. It was a firebase permission error, I had not updated my rules.

Answer (score 0):

To create a user-document for a newly signed-up user, you can do the following:

1. Access their bid from the user object (like you already did).
2. Create a document reference whose path ends in the above mid. Be aware that this document does not exist yet.
3. Use the setDoc method with above document reference, and user data to be stored as inputs.

It looks like the following in the form of code:

```
const uid = res.user.uid;
const data = {
    id: uid,
    email,
    username,
};
const ref = collection(db, `users/${uid}`);
setDoc(ref, data)
    .then(() => console.log("Created New User Document Successfully"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error"))
```

You must write the above code right after your dispatch call. Hope this helps!